# Find dates with lower revenue than yesterday

Tags: sql, date

I'm fairly new to BQ SQL and am stuck on a query regarding dates.
I have a table that consists of `customer_id` (int), `date_purchase` (date), `sales` (int).

The query is to find all `customer_id` and `date_purchase` with lower sales compared to the previous `date_purchase` (yesterday).

I've tried many things but not sure how to execute the code to work.
I also could not code to automatically identify today and yesterday's date, so have manually input it.
Below are sections that I think need to be put together but I could be wrong.

```
select id, revenue 
from (
    SELECT id, date_purchase as today, revenue 
    from SALES 
    where date_purchase>='2022-05-29'
) t1 
-- unsure how to join these
(
    SELECT id, date_purchase as yesterday, revenue 
    from SALES 
    where datepurchase='2022-05-28'
)t2 on t1.id=t2.id 
where t1.revenue<t2.revenue
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Literally, where the `-- unsure how to join these` comment is located, simply replace that with `join`.

Also, in the outer select, need to specify *which specific columns* from the `t1` or `t2` aliases to avoid ambiguity, because *both* derived table queries (in the `from` clause) have `id` and `revenue` references. (alternatively, you could rename these columns within the selects like was done with the `data_purchase` column to avoid ambiguity)

Example: (I've assumed the data from t1 is desired in the select)

```
select t1.id, t1.revenue
from (
    SELECT id, date_purchase as today, revenue 
    from SALES 
    where date_purchase >= '2022-05-29'
) t1 
join
(
    SELECT id, date_purchase as yesterday, revenue 
    from SALES 
    where date_purchase = '2022-05-28'
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
where t1.revenue < t2.revenue;
```

Using this sample data:

[image]

Gives this output:

[image]

Example [DB fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1d16931384a11915cf75e4e2a43b1cac)

Though it may be a new concept to you, know that a self-join of the `SALES` table can achieve the same results with less SQL syntax. I added a self-join example as the last query in the DB fiddle.